# Styling of ui.list (autoheight or css overflow)

Tags: list, css, listview, webix

I'm trying to customize the style of the Webix ui.list widget, but there're two questions that I can't solve by myself:

- is there a way to set the autoheight for items?
- if no, which class will allow to set `text-overflow:ellipsis?

Here's a [sample](http://webix.com/snippet/71f65a95) and the code of the current implementation:

**CSS:**

```
.webix_list_item{
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin:15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  
  background: #fafafa;    
}

.webix_list_item:hover{  
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(177,44,99,0.6);
  border: 1px solid #efefef;  
  background: #efefef;
}

.webix_list_item.webix_selected {
  color: #fff;
  background: #cac1c5;
  border: 1px solid #bfb8bb !important;
}
```

**JS** (pretty simple):

```
webix.ui({  
  view:"list",
  data:list_data, 
  width:230, scroll:false,  
  select:true
});
```

Comment: @kukkuz yep, thank you, but imho the `type` will be even better here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the CSS solution, Webix list has a `type` property which can handle the height of the items. Particularly:

```
type:{
    height:"auto"
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/c01714d0

Answer (score 2):

Trivial, is this what you are expecting?

http://webix.com/snippet/0e340ea4

I have added the below css:

```
  .webix_list_item {
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

if you want to set autoheight:

```
  .webix_list_item {
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: visible !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
```